# Javascript: parse JSON with variables

Tags: javascript, json, eval

I would like to know how to execute this code without errors.

```
var test = 'Something';
JSON.parse('{"xxx": test}');
```

The reason i'm asking this i have a JSON object with variables i want to use inside a data attribute. I would like to parse the JSON into an object. When have this i can use eval() to run it with the variables.

Comment: you could do `JSON.parse('{"xxx": "' + test + '"}');`

Comment: @mast3rd3mon — Won't work, `{"xxx": Something }` is also invalid JSON … and it doesn't solve the problem of having the data in a data attribute and not a script.

Comment: @Quentin see my edit on the comment

Comment: @mast3rd3mon — That's fragile (it will fail if `test` contains `"`, new lines, etc). It also doesn't address the second part of my comment.

Comment: @Quentin i would assume the code in question will be inside a js file, so how are html data attributes relevant here?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon — Read the sentence immediately after the code in the question!

Comment: @Quentin the op states he wants to use the json object the parse creates inside data attributes, not the code itself

Comment: @mast3rd3mon — They say they have JSON inside a data attribute. They are reading the data attribute and then parsing it as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

JSON doesn't support variables.

It is a data format based on JS syntax. It is not a complete copy of the JS programming language.

Comment: Ok, then i'm going to construct the JSON inside a JS file. Thanks

Comment: @Mayhem — If you are constructing it in JS and are going to use it in JS then just create an object. Forget about JSON.

Comment: I just noticed, JSON.parse has a optional reviver function. Tomorrow i'm going to try not to set the variables in the data attribute. Add them afterwards with the reviver function. First results look good.